# Android - simple Button rotation

Tags: android, button, rotation

I want the button to be displayed at a 90 degree rotation, as simple as that. Any suggestions?

```
<Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/systeminfo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="0.433"
            android:background="@drawable/thumbnail_big"
            android:textColor="#ff000000"
            android:textSize="30dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
findViewById(R.id.systeminfo).setRotation(90);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use setRotation() in your java class.From API 11 added a [setRotation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29) method to all views.

**example**

```
view.setRotation(degree);
```